# Iterating through a get_connections("me","friends")...is this inefficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my user model I have a `friends` method that returns the hash of all the user's facebook friends. In my view I iterate through the entire list to paginate that list alphabetically. I can't tell if my server is running really slow or if this is extremely inefficient. How can I make this process faster? Is it better to maybe create a `friends`model? Please let me know if my method is inefficient, why, and how I might be able to make it faster. Thanks!

In my Home.html.erb view I have `<%letter ='a'%>` which changes when the user selects a different letter and the page refreshes.

```
<% current_user.friends.each do |user| %>
    <% if user['name'].downcase.start_with? letter %>
       do something
<% end %>
```

User Model

```
def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
    block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
    logger.info e.to_s
    nil
end

def friends
    facebook {|fb| fb.get_connections("me","friends")}.sort{|a,b| a['name']<=>b['name']}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an external API call for every request. Plus user may have good number of friends like 500, 1000.

I in my fb app processing the data in background job(delayed job). You can use resque or sidekiq or some other background to process user data.

I would suggest you to make Friend model and have its association with users model. Then if you have some n+1 query problem you can use `includes` and instead of using `sort` use `order` it would be much faster then `sort`. Moreover instead of using `each` use `find_each` it will process the data in chunks you can google the difference between each and find_each. hope it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will be slowing down each request for sure is the fact that your making an external API call in the middle of the request. The second thing to note is that your potentially bringing back a large amount of data, easily getting into the hundreds, if not thousands.

A more appropriate way to handle this would be to create a Friend model where each friend has a belongs to relationship to the User. In a background processor (ie delayed job, resque, sidekiq), iterate through your users and update their friends at some interval that your server can tolerate. It will cause some lag as to when the user's friends will show up. You'll have to be the judge as to how much lag time is tolerable, and it depends largely on your number of users and budget for hardware.

This is effectively a caching mechanism, and you may want to account for the fact that data will change, friends may be removed and so on. You could delete all the friends and recreate the whole list on each refresh. Doing so inside a transaction will keep the deletes from showing up until it is commited.